# JQuery hasClass is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im learning Jquery and Im trying to check if a `span` has a certain class, this is the `span` in question:

```
  <span class="recaptcha-checkbox goog-inline-block
                 recaptcha-checkbox-unchecked recaptcha-checkbox-checked
                 rc-anchor-checkbox recaptcha-checkbox-expired" role="checkbox"
        aria-checked="false" id="recaptcha-anchor" tabindex="0"
        dir="ltr" aria-labelledby="recaptcha-anchor-label">
    <div class="recaptcha-checkbox-border" role="presentation" style=""></div>
    <div class="recaptcha-checkbox-borderAnimation" role="presentation" style=""></div>
    <div class="recaptcha-checkbox-spinner" role="presentation"></div><div class="recaptcha-checkbox-spinnerAnimation" role="presentation"></div>
    <div class="recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark" role="presentation"></div>
  </span>
```

The idea is to check if the `<span>` have the class `recaptcha-checkbox-checked`

So in regards of the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/):

> *"The .hasClass() method will return true if the class is assigned to an element, even if other classes also are."*

So I have the following:

```
captchaStatus: function () {
    return $("#recaptcha-anchor").hasClass("recaptcha-checkbox-checked")

}
```

It is always returning false even if the element have the class.

EDIT:

```
var AddressValidatorHelper = {
    AddressValidator: function () {
        if (!AddressValidatorHelper.changedAddress && AddressValidatorHelper.clickedVerify
            && AddressValidatorHelper.captchaStatus() && ValidatorControls.validate()) {
            AddressValidatorHelper.noNormHide();
            return true;

        }
        else {
            if (!AddressValidatorHelper.alreadyAppended) {
                AddressValidatorHelper.noNormAppend();
                AddressValidatorHelper.noNormShow();
                AddressValidatorHelper.alreadyAppended = true;
            }
            if (AddressValidatorHelper.changedAddress) {
                AddressValidatorHelper.noNormShow();
            }
            if (AddressValidatorHelper.clickedVerify) {
                AddressValidatorHelper.noNormHide();
            }

            return false;
        }
    },

    noNormAppend: function () { $("#verDom").append("<label class='control-label' id='validarDom' style='color='#a94442'>Valide su domicilio</label>") },
    noNormShow: function () { $("#validarDom").show() },
    noNormHide: function () { $("#validarDom").hide() },
    changedAddress: false,
    clickedVerify: false,
    alreadyAppended: false,
    captchaStatus: function () {
        return $("#recaptcha-anchor").hasClass("recaptcha-checkbox-checked")

    }
}
```

So Im calling `AddressValidatorHelper.captchaStatus()`

Comment: Add a working example that show the returning false

Comment: The posted code works as expected. Please post all of the relevant code so we can help better.

Comment: You should not have `div` elements inside of `span` elements. They are meant to go the other way around.

Comment: Yep, it is returning 0 Taplar

Comment: Scott, talk to google, that's ReCaptcha v2.0

Comment: Then that element doesn't exist on the page at the time you are running that logic.  Or you're selector for it is incorrect and it is not finding it.  Either way, hasClass() on no matched element will always return false.

Comment: Mmmmm... that is so weird, because the captcha is always there and when I ask it's there I can check the html even or see it in the page.

Comment: How are you checking the html?  View Page Source or Inspecting Elements?

Comment: That is a great question Taplar, because I dont have to use .html(), with $("#recaptcha-anchor") works in the console...

Comment: Scripts ran in the console are highly likely to be after the point that the element is created on the page.  But it does not at the time that that method runs, which is why you are seeing the zero.  If you want to see this more, you can put `debugger;` as the first line of captchaStatus and it will cause your browser's debugger to pause the script and give you a chance to look around and examine things if you are doubtful.

Comment: *"It is always returning false even if the element have the class."* that is impossible. either it doesn't have the class, or you aren't running .hasClass on what you think you are.

Comment: I just doubled checked one of my sites that uses the recaptcha.  Until it is initialized, those elements do not exist on the page.  And if you do the destroy logic to cleanup after it is used, the elements are removed.  So at this point i'm 99.99% sure you are just having a timing issue.

Comment: I think is timing issues too, sometimes by that id exists, at some other moment it exists... I have to check what it is doing.

Answer (score -2):

Please encapsulate your js code inside [jquery ready function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45743295/my-div-when-clicked-doesnt-submit-the-form-inside-of-it-with-js/45743507#45743507)

```
$(function(){
 //your has class checking code here 
})
```

Comment: How do you know it's not?  And if the element doesn't exist on the page at the time he runs the script, a doc ready isn't going to save you.  That doesn't stop your script from running a lookup before elements are dynamically created.